# Пишу своего бота на aiogram который должен пересылать новые сообщения из канала. Почему-то не работает

Tags: aiogram, python-2.x

**Пишу бота на aiogram
Почему то не пересылается новое сообщение с тг канала в лс с ботом. Проверьте код и подскажите что не так.** *Версия питона **2.9***

```
import asyncio
import requests
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

API_TOKEN = 'токен бота'
CHANNEL_ID = 'Айди канала'
YOUR_CHAT_ID = 'мой йайди'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


async def fetch_new_posts():
    while True:
        url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{API_TOKEN}/getChatHistory?chat_id={CHANNEL_ID}'
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            if data['ok'] and data['result']:
                post_text = data['result'][0]['message']['text']
                await bot.send_message(chat_id='361823582', text=post_text)
        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Проверка каждую минуту


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Привет! Я бот, который пересылает новые посты из других телеграм каналов.")


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling()
    await asyncio.create_task(fetch_new_posts())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Программа завершена пользователем.")
```

Comment: А бот имеет доступ к постам?

Comment: Нужна отладка. В первую очередь стоить проверить, что именно у вас получается в переменной **url** и потом уже посмотреть, что именно приходит в ответ на запрос, т.е. что в переменной **response**.  Возможно это вам поможет сильнее, чем кто-то тут на сайте.

Comment: CausonQ да бот состоит в тг канале и в боте отключен на всякий случай privacy mode

Comment: @VladimirIgnatenko отладку делаю ставлю точку останова на строке с url. После чего захожу в тг в тестовый канал пишу пост захожу обратно к отладке нечего не меняется. Что может быть не так. Вроде айди канала указывал правильно